# Fat Free PHP SEO Friendly URLs

Tags: php, seo, fat-free-framework

I'm looking into using F3 for more of my projects. I love the routing feature and the ability to produce dynamic routes for using with conventions like:

```
$f3->route('GET /@controller/@action', '@controller->@action');
```

One thing I need is seo-friendly URLs so I can do something like:

```
/two-words/two-more-words
```

as a controller/action combo.  I've tried this in code as well as searched as far as I can see for examples on how to accomplish this, but thus far, I've been unsuccessful.  Basically, the dash in the url will not resolve to a class/method (controller/action) combo in the routes.

Is there a way to do this so that dashes either get replaced by empty characters or some other way to get the routes to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you really want it that way you could use a lambda function for this:

```
f3->route('GET /@controller/@action', function($f3,$params){
  $class = str_replace('-','',$params['controller']);
  $method= str_replace('-','',$params['action']);
  $f3->call( $class.'->'.$method );
});
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for, some kind of hook to convert SEO URLs into class/method names. perfect, thanks!  Though, why do you say "if you really want it that way?" Is there something wrong with this practice? lower-cased, hyphen-separated URLs are part of our standards.

Comment: I think the only drawback to this method is that our team is not going to like that you can get to a URL from several different combinations e.g., two-word-controller/action, two-wo-r-d-con-trol-ler/action would both resolve to the same URL.  If there's no way around that, then there's no way around it.

Comment: no.. there's nothing wrong with it ;) maybe it's just a personal feeling about possibly exposing all controllers and methods. i like it more strict, and define more single routes than a one that fits all :)

Comment: well you could explode the controller and action parameter on the `-` chars and make the first char of its part an uppercase. that way you could build camelCase names for class and methods, which solves your concerns about multiple routes leading to the same action

Comment: @ikez, I'm not entirely sure I'm going to use it this way. I'm coming from almost 100% utilization of a framework called LightVC, and I wanted to see what similarities F3 had with LVC.  I'm also a .net developer by profession so I also wanted to see if some of the things we do in .net MVC could translate to F3.  In the end, I might go with the single route setup as well, but I did have concerns about that getting unwieldy, as well as possible performance issues when it came to sites with a large amount of routes.  I'm an infant with F3 now, so this is me, exploring. Thanks!